# How do I disable notifications from Documentation?

Tags: support, documentation, notifications

I've apparently managed to enable notifications for the Javascript Language topic over in documentation. I get pinged for every single new topic request and it's becoming quite annoying.

Would it be possible to disable that somewhere? Or maybe just ping me if there's a comment/edit/whatever on some example/topic I actually participated in?

I really don't want to get pinged every time someone suggests creating a new topic because they seem to be pretty imaginative when it comes to coming up with things to suggest.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can disable it on the tag's dashboard itself.

[image]

Comment: To get to this, open the notification, scroll to the top, then click on dashboard.

Comment: An apostrophe is missing in "tags". I went nearly about to ask where the "tags dashboard" was.

Comment: @E_net4 Fixed ^^

Comment: This was quite non-obvious; I've been going into my Profile > Preferences page every few weeks looking for a toggle for this until I eventually decided to look on meta for a solution. I did look at the dashboard and didn't see the grey text - though, I suppose I know where to look now.