# How to receive Notifications from Documentation

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

How get notifications about any changes in documentation fonctionality?

Comment: Strongly related: [How do I **disable** notifications from Documentation?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328464/419956)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want just to share with you how to get notification from Documentations about any news about my Tags or the new topics or the topics which need improvement, so it is easy:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation
2. choose your Tag: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/[mytag]
3. choose Dashboard
4. you can see notification (eye) like that:

[image]

5. now choose your mode of notification like that:

[image]

Now you can get notifications from documentation.

I hope this help some of you.