# Make All Documentation Notification Subscriptions Configurable in One Place

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, notifications, global-inbox

For a while now, I have been receiving inbox notifications for "proposed change", "topic request", etc. for topics on Documentation that I am not interested in.

When digging deep enough through the interface for those topics, can find where to disable the notifications as detailed in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328486/), but that is tedious. *(still puzzled how these were turned on in the first place, as they are topics I'm not involved with)*.

Is there a way to see *all* of the notifications you are subscribed to and remove them, without having to locate each individual topic and then check three separate panels to make sure they are all set to "No Notifications"?

I think there should be a single dashboard to review and/or configure Documentation notifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the [February 6th update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343091/documentation-update-february-6th), there's now a watching tab on your profile (under documentation) that lists all of the things you're subscribed to.

[image: Watching tab]

Comment: That is awesome news, thanks Kevin and the team.

Comment: This should probably be mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-notifications). Really difficult to figure out how to turn off *all* notifications at the moment. Especially since we automatically watch topics