# Documentation Review Watch

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, notifications

Starting Feb 7 I started getting informed of proposed changes and improvement request comments for documentation. These notifications appeared almost daily for languages of which I've edited content, added content, reviewed, or upvoted at some point but at no point did I click the watch all discussions button, as I dislike pointless notifications. After each notification, I clicked "unwatch all discussions" but they keep coming from different languages.

- proposed change-python, jquery, vim, javascript, grep, c
- improvement request comment-bash, vim

Is there a bug that auto-enrolled me in the watch discussion when I edited, added, reviewed, or voted on content?

From this [Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341485/3462319) there seems to be a way to un-watch all from my profile but there are two issues.

1. It shows issues I've already unwatched
2. Clicking "unwatch all discussions" just takes me to the top of the page and the topic is still there on scrolling down.

Comment: The auto-enrollment is intentional, see the *Watching Discussion and Managing Notifications* section [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343091/247702): *"Based on the number of requests we've seen for ways to monitor a topic, we've also decided to opt anyone who makes a non-trivial change (read: has the potential for rep gain) into watching the topics they edit. These opt-ins have been backfilled."*

Comment: @Stijn that is good to know the reason, any idea on why I can't unwatch discussions from my profile?

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Comment: The unwatch seems a little buggy for me. Had to click it a few times, refresh the page, etc.

Comment: I'm gonna bring this up with the team next week. The "unwatch all discussions" toggle does seem temperamental.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there was a transient javascript error behind some of this behavior.  I can no longer reproduce that.

There was another bug that has been fixed.  Unwatching (or watching, for that matter) a whole topic's discussion now clears all single-item watches on that topic.